# How to set below image grid using display flex

Tags: html, css

I have try to set using flex. please check my demo [my code](https://jsfiddle.net/uyrbjL3a/1/)
its possible using flote but my required using flex.[image]
I set it up using Flex but I not found success in it. You help me...

**my code**

```css
.cg-box-layout-two{display: -ms-flexbox;display: flex;-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;flex-wrap: wrap;align-items: stretch;position: relative;}
.cg-box-layout-two .cg-box-name{flex: 0 0 100%;max-width: 100%;}
.cg-box-layout-two .cg-layout-img{flex: 0 0 36%;max-width:36%;box-sizing: border-box;border-radius: 6px;overflow: hidden;box-shadow:0 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);position: relative;}
.cg-box-layout-two .cg-layout-img .cg-our-top-pick{position: absolute;background-color: #77b21d;color: #fff;font-size: 12px;font-weight: 700;text-transform: uppercase;padding: 4px 0px;transform: rotate(45deg);right: -68px;top: -23px;transform-origin: 0 0;width: 153px;box-sizing: border-box;text-align: center;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;box-shadow: 1px 2px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);}
.cg-box-layout-two .cg-layout-img .cg-li-photo{max-height:220px;padding: 32px 4px 16px;box-sizing: border-box;}
.cg-box-layout-two .cg-layout-content{flex: 0 0 calc(64% - 15px);max-width:calc(64% - 15px);box-sizing: border-box;padding:16px;position: relative;box-shadow:0px 0px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);border-radius: 6px;overflow: hidden;margin-left: 15px;}
.cg-box-layout-two .cg-layout-img .cg-li-photo img{max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 180px;}
    
    .cg-rate{position: relative;font-size: 20px;color: #0d3153;font-weight: bold;line-height: 20px;text-align: center;display: inline-block;padding: 0 15px;min-width: 100px;}
.cg-rate>span{font-size: 14px;display: block;line-height: 14px;}
.cg-rate:before,
.cg-rate:after{content: "";position: absolute;left: 0px;height: 31px;width: 15px;background-size: 100%;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-image:url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA8AAAAfCAMAAAAP3mfjAAAAb1BMVEUAAAANMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVMNMVN1VGFuAAAAJHRSTlMA82fJ6LAjEgaim3U93YpINs24V00N4tS9kX9vYFMrHxqolkKuk4aZAAAA40lEQVQY002PiRKDIAxEEw5F8b5q1dYe+//fWBgRmxkGHskmGwqRVq2/Ipbg8z26YwF5ci5fpIH6ZInS6LmI2hl4UCG+JrAA1g7+M0QF6bA7oFh2arJy+oyxeiOq77kJeYDTO1Be47AAsNFqBgX48mi4KR66CpDJfKceyAO7Vuo1ASJwwi4H3JJT3UhwWa18LWQM1ZcgHbbE77+dAwCsM3iwoaGCa8e94vT4eHaqXVIL9PQXH0BkY5BUbyHAFvoQ8NHhDTzJh3Wsaj9pCAIxGPKmdoq2u0m3OuKX4Re90i0gE6If9SsTmsaqO/oAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');}
.cg-rate:after{left: auto;right: 0px;top: 0;transform: rotateY(180deg);}
.cg-box-layout-two .cg-layout-img .cg-li-ratebadge,
.cg-box-layout-one .cg-layout-img .cg-li-ratebadge{margin:12px auto;text-align: center;}
```

```html
<div class="cg-box-layout-two cg-red">
        <div class="cg-layout-img">
            <div class="cg-our-top-pick">Our Top Pick</div>
            <div class="cg-li-photo">
                <a href="https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01AZC3I6U/?tag=10b-gm-20" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="cg-aff-link ">
                    <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41h0H4SCgPL.jpg" class="cg-img-1" alt="Best Projector Under $200">
                </a>            </div>
            <div class="cg-li-ratebadge"><div class="cg-rate"><span>7.8/10</span> <span>Our Score</span></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="cg-layout-content">
            <div class="cg-text">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt est vitae ultrices accumsan. Aliquam ornare lacus adipiscing, posuere lectus et, fringilla augue.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt est vitae ultrices accumsan.&nbsp;</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt est vitae ultrices accumsan. Aliquam ornare lacus adipiscing, posuere lectus et, fringilla augue.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt est vitae ultrices accumsan.&nbsp;</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt est vitae ultrices accumsan. Aliquam ornare lacus adipiscing, posuere lectus et, fringilla augue.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt est vitae ultrices accumsan.&nbsp;</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt est vitae ultrices accumsan. Aliquam ornare lacus adipiscing, posuere lectus et, fringilla augue.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt est vitae ultrices accumsan.&nbsp;</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt est vitae ultrices accumsan. Aliquam ornare lacus adipiscing, posuere lectus et, fringilla augue.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt est vitae ultrices accumsan.&nbsp;</p>            </div>
            <div class="cg-lc-button">
                <a href="https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01AZC3I6U/?tag=10b-gm-20" class="cg-btn cg-red cg-aff-link" data-style="default" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Check Price</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: https://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/WD/wds4p6.html

Comment: without float to set

Comment: does the size of your image and paragraph vary?

Comment: @weilory yes but you can use fix size for image box

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I modified.

- I used two flex boxes, the first one has a direction of column, which contains tow vertical objects. the second one has a direction of row, which contains two horizontal objects. the image and the upper box are grouped into the second flex box since they have to show at the same row. the first flex box wraps everything.
- I assigned a fixed height of the image box, `290px`, since I've used JS to rearrange layout meanwhile detecting overflow occasions.

```js
const upperText = document.querySelector('.cg-layout-content');
const lowerText = document.querySelector('.cg-layout-below');


function paragraphAppender(...sentences){
    let flag = false;
    for(let i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++){
        let pNode = document.createTextNode(sentences[i]);
        if(flag){
            lowerText.appendChild(pNode);
        }else{
            let beforeAdd = 290;
            upperText.appendChild(pNode);
            if(upperText.getBoundingClientRect().height > beforeAdd){
                flag = true;
                upperText.removeChild(pNode);
            }
        }
    }
}

let exp = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt est vitae ultrices accumsan. Aliquam ornare lacus adipiscing, posuere lectus et, fringilla augue.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt est vitae ultrices accumsan.&nbsp;';
paragraphAppender(exp, exp, exp, exp);
```

```css
.flex-row{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top: 2vmin;
}

.flex-column{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.cg-box-layout-two{
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    position: relative;
}

.cg-box-layout-two .cg-box-name{
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.cg-box-layout-two .cg-layout-img{
    flex: 0 0 36%;
    max-width:36%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow:0 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    position: relative;
}

.cg-box-layout-two .cg-layout-img .cg-our-top-pick{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #77b21d;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 4px 0px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    right: -68px;
    top: -23px;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    width: 153px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.cg-box-layout-two .cg-layout-img .cg-li-photo{
    max-height:220px;
    padding: 32px 4px 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cg-box-layout-two .cg-layout-content{
    flex: 0 0 calc(64% - 15px);
    max-width:calc(64% - 15px);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding:16px;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-radius: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.cg-layout-below{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding:16px;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-radius: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cg-box-layout-two .cg-layout-img .cg-li-photo img{
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 180px;
}

    
    .cg-rate{
        position: relative;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #0d3153;
        font-weight: bold;
        line-height: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0 15px;
        min-width: 100px;
    }

.cg-rate>span{
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 14px;
}

.cg-rate:before,
.cg-rate:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    height: 31px;
    width: 15px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image:url('data:image/png;base64,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');
}

.cg-rate:after{
    left: auto;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.cg-box-layout-two .cg-layout-img .cg-li-ratebadge,
.cg-box-layout-one .cg-layout-img .cg-li-ratebadge{
    margin:12px auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='flex-column'>
<div class="cg-box-layout-two cg-red">
    <div class='flex-row'>
            <div class="cg-layout-img">
                <div class="cg-our-top-pick">Our Top Pick</div>
                <div class="cg-li-photo">
                    <a href="https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01AZC3I6U/?tag=10b-gm-20" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="cg-aff-link ">
                        <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41h0H4SCgPL.jpg" class="cg-img-1" alt="Best Projector Under $200">
                    </a>            </div>
                <div class="cg-li-ratebadge"><div class="cg-rate"><span>7.8/10</span> <span>Our Score</span></div></div>
            </div>

            <div class="cg-layout-content">
                <div class="cg-text">
                    <!-- <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt est vitae ultrices accumsan. Aliquam ornare lacus adipiscing, posuere lectus et, fringilla augue.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt est vitae ultrices accumsan.&nbsp;</p> -->
    <!-- <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt est vitae ultrices accumsan. Aliquam ornare lacus adipiscing, posuere lectus et, fringilla augue.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt est vitae ultrices accumsan.&nbsp;</p>             -->
                </div>
                <div class="cg-lc-button">
                    <a href="https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01AZC3I6U/?tag=10b-gm-20" class="cg-btn cg-red cg-aff-link" data-style="default" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Check Price</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cg-layout-below">
            <div class="cg-text">
                <!-- <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt est vitae ultrices accumsan. Aliquam ornare lacus adipiscing, posuere lectus et, fringilla augue.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt est vitae ultrices accumsan.&nbsp;</p> -->
<!-- <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt est vitae ultrices accumsan. Aliquam ornare lacus adipiscing, posuere lectus et, fringilla augue.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt est vitae ultrices accumsan.&nbsp;</p> -->
<!-- <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt est vitae ultrices accumsan. Aliquam ornare lacus adipiscing, posuere lectus et, fringilla augue.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt est vitae ultrices accumsan.&nbsp;</p>             -->
            </div>
            <div class="cg-lc-button">
                <a href="https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01AZC3I6U/?tag=10b-gm-20" class="cg-btn cg-red cg-aff-link" data-style="default" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Check Price</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here are a few things to notice:

- Paragraph contends are directly injected into `.cg-layout-content` and `.cg-layout-below`, since `.cg-text` has no text styling. in addition I don't know how you are going to arrange `<a href="https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01AZC3I6U/?tag=10b-gm-20" class="cg-btn cg-red cg-aff-link" data-style="default" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Check Price</a>`.
- by using this method, you must make sure there are some context to write in as paragraph, otherwise the layout mess up.